# VB.Net WebAPI 2 Not filtering records

Tags: c#, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am just starting to learn web API2 controllers and and have some difficulty. In C# it is working well calling all records and filtering as well, but with VB.Net it works well fetching all records but it is NOT working when filtering for specific record. Here are the codes:

C# Code which is working fine:

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.ToList();
        }
    }

    public Employee Get(int id)
    {
        using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
        {
            return entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

VB.Net Code which works fine only when getting all records, but not when filtering for specific record:

```
Public Class EmployeesController
    Inherits ApiController

    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of Employee)
        Using entities As EmployeeDBEntities = New EmployeeDBEntities()
            Return entities.Employees.ToList
        End Using
    End Function

    Public Function GetValues(vID As Integer) As Employee
        Using entities As EmployeeDBEntities = New EmployeeDBEntities()
            Return entities.Employees.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.ID = vID)
        End Using
    End Function

End Class
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your VB code is equivalent to the original C# code (except that you don't need to rename your methods - '[Get]' will work fine) - your problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas, Not sure what I might be missing in here,,, getting all records work just fine in both and filtering in C# works also, but only the filter section in VB not working,,, ?